# Streamlit AgGrid, output table does not update values after being changed

Tags: python, pandas, ag-grid, streamlit

I am building a table that updates the values of an output DF into a csv file (or whatever output defined).

I defined a `generate_agrid(df)` function that outputs a class that contains a `data` method that is a `pd.DataFrame`. When I run the code `grid_table = generate_agrid(df)`, the `grid_table` generated contains the original df, even if I modify it in the `UI`. I noticed that when I checked the input that my `update` function received.

What I want is to:

**Graph the data in df -> update DF data in the UI and return -> save new df data into a csv every time I press update button**

#### Why does my `generate_agrid` method always returns the initial DF used as an input? How can i update it?

### My code

```
import streamlit as st

from metrics.get_metrics import get_data

from metrics.config import PATH_SAMPLES
filename: str = 'updated_sample.csv'
save_path = PATH_SAMPLES.joinpath(filename)


def generate_agrid(data: pd.DataFrame):
    gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(data)
    gb.configure_default_column(editable=True)  # Make columns editable
    gb.configure_pagination(paginationAutoPageSize=True)  # Add pagination
    gb.configure_side_bar()  # Add a sidebar
    gb.configure_selection('multiple', use_checkbox=True,
                           groupSelectsChildren="Group checkbox select children")  # Enable multi-row selection
    gridOptions = gb.build()

    grid_response = AgGrid(
        data,
        gridOptions=gridOptions,
        data_return_mode=DataReturnMode.AS_INPUT,
        update_on='MANUAL',  # <- Should it let me update before returning?
        fit_columns_on_grid_load=False,
        theme=AgGridTheme.STREAMLIT,  # Add theme color to the table
        enable_enterprise_modules=True,
        height=350,
        width='100%',
        reload_data=True
    )

    data = grid_response['data']
    selected = grid_response['selected_rows']
    df = pd.DataFrame(selected)  # Pass the selected rows to a new dataframe df
    return grid_response

def update(grid_table: classmethod, filename: str = 'updated_sample.csv'):
    save_path = PATH_SAMPLES.joinpath(filename)
    grid_table_df = pd.DataFrame(grid_table['data'])
    grid_table_df.to_csv(save_path, index=False)

# First data gather
df = get_data() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start graphing
    grid_table = generate_agrid(df)
    
    # Update
    st.sidebar.button("Update", on_click=update, args=[grid_table])
```

Comment: In `grid_table = generate_agrid(df)` under main where is this df coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was just a small parameter that was activated.

While instantiating the AgGrid, I had to eliminate the `reload_data=True` parameter. Doing that, everything worked as expected and the data could be successfully updated after manually inputting and pressing `"update"`

This is how AgGrid must be instantiated

```
grid_response = AgGrid(
        data,
        gridOptions=gridOptions,
        data_return_mode=DataReturnMode.AS_INPUT,
        update_on='MANUAL',  
        fit_columns_on_grid_load=False,
        theme=AgGridTheme.STREAMLIT,  # Add theme color to the table
        enable_enterprise_modules=True,
        height=350,
        width='100%',
    )
```

Comment: In my case, I just needed to delete the parameter `update_mode=GridUpdateMode.SELECTION_CHANGED` while AgGrid instantiating